# Is it acceptable to return in middle of class __construct()

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I know that there is a lot of questions which are close to this. However, I did not manage to find answer to simple question (*I am NOT asking about returning values from constructor and I think that I understand what constructors should return*).

#### Is there any reasons to avoid using `return` within `__construct`?

Or is this fully acceptable coding style that does not break in future because of `return`:

```php
class A {
    protected $tristate = null;
    function __construct() {
        // Constructor returns instance of class automatically
        // no need to `return $this`
    }
    protected function Logic() {
        return rand(0, 1) === 1;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($this->Logic()) return;
        $this->tristate = true;
    }
}
```

Above one is tested and it working as expected (*within my development environment*), it sets parent `$tristate` var 50/50 to NULL/TRUE but will it work in future and could there be any problems arising when returning in a middle of constructor with `void return`.

Another thing that came into mind is should I use `return $this` instead of plain `return` which is normally void but PHP seems to return instance anyway, answer may well be that both `return $this` and plain `return` is just as good.

Comment: This class is just simplified example as my question is not about returning something (_anything special_) other than normal class instance from its constructor. I am asking about `return`ìng at middle of constructor and possible problems in returning void (_seemingly replaced by PHP engine_) in middle of constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

> Constructor
>   void __construct ([ mixed $args [, $... ]] )

and from  [pseudo type definition](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php)

> void as a return type means that the return value is useless.

So you can return anything... but it's `useless`. In your case the `return` works for exit from function execution: it's simply allowed.

Another question is if it's a good or bad practice...

I think that the simple `return ;` is a good practice for save some IF statement and annoying indentation.
A return with value (ie `return false;`), if it's useless, is a bad practice because has no sense.

Answer (score 3):

There are no ramifications to this and I don't think there ever will be. You can return anything and at any time from a constructor. The return value, if any, is ignored.

Comment: In fact I can't return _just about anything_ because constructor should always return object or in case of failure throw error / (return null?). But hey, you already said that and I'm just repeating it.

Comment: That's not what I said. It does not matter what or when you return.

Comment: Got it. I was thinking about really getting something from outside the box... So return value is ignored today, is there any reasons that could make us wait for __constructor that could really return something else for example for quick error handling like `if (!$obj=new MyClass()) die('error');`.

Comment: I can't imagine this will ever change. It would break backwards compatibility pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good rule of thumb to ensure that *no* method `return`s early - aside from anything else, it means that in 6 months time, when you come back to that 1500 line function that you know you shouldn't really have written, but did it anyway, you have a slightly less nightmarish time of understanding how the heck the stupid thing works :)

By using a negated logic check - `if ( ! $this->Logic() )` you get the same effect as returning early, but you can now come back to the code knowing it's never going to randomly drop out of your method somewhere in the middle of it.

Of course, there's nothing stopping you doing it except the little voice saying "I know I shouldn't", but there's another voice saying "Oh go on, it'll be fine, you'll remember that!". Don't listen to the second voice, and just do it properly :P

---

Quick update to be clear - there are no technical reasons to avoid `return`ing in a constructor (the `new` keyword forces it to return the object, and overrides what the constructor returns), there is an excellent *logical* reason not to do it.

Comment: "in 6 months time, when you come back to that 1500 line function that you know you shouldn't really have written, but did it anyway" - dude, get out of my head.

Comment: There's a lot of people who feel that the early exit is actually a smart way to keep code clean. It tends to reduce unneeded nesting. This is also my opinion. Not trying to argue, but I do think this is a rather subjective opinion.

Comment: If you write a 1500 line function/method you should hang you head in shame. It should just fit onto a page/screen. If not, break it up a little. You should be able to see bot the top and bottom of a function/method on a screen. That is about (at most) 100 lines of code. **THIS IS BEING POLITE ABOUT 1500 LINES OF CODE IN A FUNCTION **

Comment: *"It's a good rule of thumb to ensure that no method returns early"* Why? So we can have a bazillion booleans and/or nested ifs that obfuscate what we are actually trying to do? Sounds great.

Comment: @Ed and NullUserException, it's fine to say that, and I agree with you (and that much should be obvious from the answer). In practice, you're going to see it happen even if it's because you inherit it. At work, we have many 10k+ line files, and a fair few 2k+ line functions. Yes it's terrible, but saying "God that's bad" doesn't help. And when they return somewhere in those lines, good luck finding it. With braces you can just step up each time to see the check it's running. In an ideal world, sure, go for it - let me know when you find an ideal world please, I'm very interested in it

Comment: so it is always same (_now and in future_). If returning by `return 'foobar';` (_which does not sound very clever_)**,** plain `return;` and PHP converts it to object for me **or** doing `return $this;` which is what PHP already does for me at end of constructor? **I have about 10-50 within most of my class constructors as I try to keep constructors just for initializing instance internally and for instructing parents.**

Comment: @Joe - I worked for ESA and if anybody generated a function like that that would have a few weekends, not enough sleep or the sack. It should be re-engineered to make a function readable and manageable. If you have that (a function with god knows how much code) you have my sympathy and I wish you good luck to understand that function. (PS Function and method are interchangeable in this context)

Comment: @Ed I envy you in that case :) You're a very lucky person (or I've committed some hideous sin in a previous life), but unsurprisingly trying to debug one of those functions (methods is what the actually are, but hey, it's late night) isn't the easiest thing in the world :) Has to be done though because refactoring it isn't going to happen, with the amount of other code that already depends on it :/

Comment: @joe - Sorry that you have to clear up the mess. If it was me I would say that those programmers need not program again - cue Peter Falk.